# Delphi: Error 2008 Incompatible types for a class property

Tags: class, delphi, syntax-error

I have this class defined

```
  TParamType = (ptDriverID, ptServer, ptHost, ptUser, ptPassword, ptPort, ptDatabase, ptOSAuth, ptPooled, ptUnicode);
  TDataType = (dtInteger, dtString, dtBoolean, dtYesNo, dtPassword);


  TParam = record
    Index: Byte;
    Typ: TParamType;
    RegKeyName: String;
    ConnName: String;
    DataType: TDataType;
    Caption: String;
    Value: String;
    Text: String;
    Default: String;
    Basic: Boolean;
    Enabled: Boolean;
    Mandatory: Boolean;
  end;

  TParams = class(TObject)
    private
      FParam: array of TParam;
      function GetParam(Index:Byte): TParam;
      procedure SetParam(Index:Byte;Value:String;Text:String);
    public
      constructor Create;
      destructor Destroy;
      property Param[Index: Byte]: TParam read GetParam write SetParam;
      procedure Enable(ServerType:TServerType);
  end;
```

I get this error: 'E2008 Incompatible types' to the code line

```
property Param[Index: Byte]: TParam read GetParam write SetParam;
```

Any idea why I get this error for this property?

Comment: FYI Just declare the property as `property Param[Index:integer] : TParam;` and press Shift-Ctrl-C for code completion, you'll love to be lazy ;o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`property Param` is a `TParam`. Therefore, `SetParam` needs to receive the `Index` into the array and a `TParam` to put there. Your setter instead provides the index and two strings, neither of which are a `TParam`.

The proper setter would be

```
procedure SetParam(Index: Byte; const Value: TParam);
```

Comment: Can you write the syntax please. I don't get your idea!

Comment: See [`Array Properties`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties#Array_Properties).

Comment: @Ken already wrote the syntax. When you declare a property, its type determines its syntax. Ken has it correct.

Comment: +1 @Ken for the Index parameter, you can't mix and match `const`. Because the property does not use `const` in the index, the getter and setter cannot. Or, if the property is `property Param[const Index: Byte]` then so would the `Index` parameter of the getter and setter. My edit makes your code compatible with that in the Q. So @REAL does have a point.

Comment: Thanks, @David: I'm in the habit of using const like that, and didn't notice it missing in the Q.